# Reduce the size of array that directly get from API

Tags: arrays, swift, rest

in my app, I get an array from an API

```
do {
  var data = try JSONDecoder().decode([NameInfo].self, from: data!)

  data.sort{$0.updated_at! > $1.updated_at!}
  completion(.success(data))
  } catch {
     print(error)
  }
```

for example in this `data` contains about 600 items which take a long time to load in the app, I just want to reduce the size of this array to 50 items directly here that this reduced array goes to the app to show. 
I tired to use this method

let limitedData = data.prefix(50)
completion(.success(limitedData))

but this error shows up:

> Member 'success' in 'Result<[NameInfo], Error>' produces result of
>   type 'Result', but context expects
>   'Result<[NameInfo], Error>'

Could anyone help me on that?
Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't have two local variables named `data`, maybe the compiler uses the wrong one when you do `data.prefix(50)` so rename the result of your decoding to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Result` expects `[NameInfo]` as `Success` type. `prefix()` method returns `ArraySlice<NameInfo>`. You need to create array from your `limitedData`:

```
let limitedData = data.prefix(50)
completion(.success(Array(limitedData)))
```